# Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and anaconda enviroments

Tags: upgrade, python, anaconda

I have a computer that runs Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm considering upgrading to 20.04. I use python virtual environments (through Anaconda) for handling scientific computing projects. Do I need to reinstall my virtual environments after the Ubuntu upgrade? Does an Ubuntu upgrade can effect existing python packages? What is the best practice to handle a similar situation after a system upgrade?